# How to get the MAX count and MIN count from a Dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

This is what I tried and got an error

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@MAXCount"

Code:

```
DECLARE @TempTable  NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @MAXCount   VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @MINCount   VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @SQLSelect  NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @TempTable = 'Test_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@@SPID)

SET @SQLSelect = 'SELECT @MAXCount = MAX(RowID), @MINCount = MIN(RowID) FROM Work_Tables.dbo.'+@TempTable+' (NOLOCK)'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLSelect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass variables as `OUTPUT` parameters:

```
DECLARE @TempTable  NVARCHAR(MAX) =  'Test_'+ '1'; -- CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@@SPID)
DECLARE @MAXCount   VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @MINCount   VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @SQLSelect  NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @SQLSelect = 'SELECT @MAXCount = MAX(RowID), @MINCount = MIN(RowID) FROM dbo.'
                  +@TempTable+' (NOLOCK)';

EXEC dbo.SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLSelect
                      ,N'@MAXCount VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT, @MinCount VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT'
                      ,@MAXCount OUTPUT
                      ,@MINCount OUTPUT;

SELECT @MAXCount, @MINCount;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/JRZU24239)**</kbd>

Notes:

1. It looks like poor design to create table per `SPID`. Related: [`SELECT * FROM sales + @yymm`](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Sales_yymm)
2. Table name should has `SYSNAME` datatype, you could add `QUOTENAME` for additional protection against SQL Injection
3. Concatenating SQL query could be error-prone, you could use `REPLACE`
4. `NOLOCK` could lead to uncommited reads.

Something like:

```
DECLARE @MAXCount   VARCHAR(10)
       ,@MINCount   VARCHAR(10);

DECLARE @SQLSelect  NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'SELECT @MAXCount = MAX(RowID), @MINCount = MIN(RowID) 
  FROM <table_name> WITH (NOLOCK)';

DECLARE @TempTable  SYSNAME =  QUOTENAME('Test_'+ '1'); -- CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@@SPID)


SET @SQLSelect = REPLACE(@SQLSelect, '<table_name>', @TempTable);

EXEC dbo.SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLSelect
                      ,N'@MAXCount VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT, @MinCount VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT'
                      ,@MAXCount OUTPUT
                      ,@MINCount OUTPUT;

SELECT @MAXCount, @MINCount;
```

Comment: Thank you that worked for me, still need to do some research on the _SYSNAME_ and _QUOTENAME_.